# Close tab index order in a container/div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hit this result: i have 2 div with their tab-index order in the same page, and when for example i'm navigating in the first div and i reach the last tab-index of that div, my focus don't go on the next div but restart from first tab-index of that div. Is this possible?

Example:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container1">
        <input tabindex="1"/>
        <input tabindex="2" />
        <input tabindex="3" />
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <input tabindex="1" />
        <input tabindex="2" />
        <input tabindex="3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to share some code so its easier to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code?

Are you using `tabindex="0"` on all of them or are you setting a specific order by using `tabindex-"1", tabindex="2"` etc.?

My suggestion without seeing your code is that you are trying to put `tabindex` on an element that doesn't allow it.

Use `tabindex="0"` on elements like `<div>`, `<span>`, `<p>` that are not keyboard focusable. They will not work with `tabindex="1"` etc. If you are going to do this though you should specify a `role="button"` etc. on that element to let a screen reader know what the purpose of the focus is for example if the user is blind.

It's hard to answer this question for you without seeing the code.

Hope this helps! If you need more help, please post your code and I'd be glad to help more.

```
<div role="button" tabindex="0">A button</div>
<div role="link" tabindex="0">A link to somewhere</div>
```

Comment: i posted a example on my first post

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. You are trying to tab through all 3 inputs in container1 and then on the fourth time pressing tab go back to input 1 in container1 right?

This would not be a good use of tabindex. Think about how frustrating that would be for a user who is physically unable to use a mouse to select inputs in container2. They could not navigate to container2 using tab on the keyboard. The whole reason for tabindex is accessibility and there are laws in place that help disadvantaged users experience the web. So even though tabindex is handy, that's not the proper use it.

Comment: i'm trying to do this because the second div is a bootstrap modal hidden. I don't know why, but on my application a simple page with a simple bootstrap modal when i try move between input in my modal after the last it go on the background. I resolve this with a event on the last tab, but when i move on address bar and press tab it go on background another time